# how to use compound bash functions from different directories

Tags: bash, awk

I have some directory e.g. /ice/cream which contains some files that I want to want to sort in size, and then find a minimum value in the largest file; however I want to do this from the parent directory /ice.

The bash line I wrote only works within /ice/cream, i'd like to make it work from /ice, I tried

```
awk 'BEGIN {min = 0} {if($7<min) min=$7} END {print min}' $(ls -lS cream/ | head -n 2 | awk '{print $9}')
```

which does not work because awk doesnt know the path to the file found by the second $() function; please help! Cheers

Comment: Put the path in front of the `$(...)` as well or use `ls -lS cream/*` but really you shouldn't be [parsing `ls`](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs) in the first place.

Comment: I tried this but get errors: awk: cmd. line:1: warning: command line argument `cream/' is a directory: skipped and: awk: cmd. line:1: fatal: cannot open file `file-15.txt' for reading (No such file or directory)

Comment: Your second suggestion with ls -lS cream/* works. Thank you :)

Answer (score 1):

A safer way to get the largest file; the call to `stat` may differ depending on your implementation:

```
max_file () {
    local max_size size
    max_size=0
    for f in "$1"/*; do
        size=$(stat -c %s "$f")
        if (( size > max_size )); then
            max_file="$f"
            max_size="$size"
        fi
    done
    echo "$max_file"
}

awk '...' "$(biggest_file cream/)"
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `ls` pipeline is way too complicated, and you need a `*` after the dir/ to get the relative name output:

```
awk 'BEGIN {min = 0} {if($7<min) min=$7} END {print min}' $(ls -S cream/* | head -1)
```

Answer (score 0):

As first answered by @Etan Reisner in comment, the line was missing a *; working code is:

```
awk 'BEGIN {min = 0} {if($7<min) min=$7} END {print min}' $(ls -lS cream/* | head -n 1 | awk '{print $9}')
```

Thank you.